# Leading and Trailing zeros are removed in formula

Tags: apex, formula

I am concatenating two number fields using formula. I am facing few issues with the formula.

```
Field 1           Field 2           Result
25.50             25.42             Actual -- 25.5 to 25.42 
                                    Expected -- 25.50 to 25.42

0.42             12.45              Actual -- .42 to 12.45
                                    Expected -- 0.42 to 12.45
```

I have used below formula for my requirement.

```
TEXT(
  IF( CONTAINS( TEXT( Number_1__c ) ,  RIGHT( TEXT(Number_1__c ) , 3) ) ,  ROUND(Number_1__c ,2) ,  
  IF( CONTAINS( TEXT(Number_1__c ) ,  RIGHT( TEXT(Number_1__c ) , 4) ) ,  ROUND(Number_1__c ,2) , 
  Number_1__c ) ) 
  ) 
  & ' to ' &
TEXT (
  IF( CONTAINS( TEXT( Number_2__c ) ,  RIGHT( TEXT(Number_2__c ) , 3) ) ,  ROUND(Number_2__c ,2) ,  
  IF( CONTAINS( TEXT(Number_2__c ) ,  RIGHT( TEXT(Number_2__c ) , 4) ) ,  ROUND(Number_2__c ,2) , 
  Number_2__c ) )
  )
```

Can someone help me to get the expected output. Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Are field1 and fields2 number(x,2)? meaning they can have 2 decimal places?

Comment: Yes, The number field has 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concatenate both the fields by converting them to "Text" and then joining them. If you know that the fields can only contain 2 decimal places, as per your comments, then you dont need to use "Round" and "Left/Right" functions to get the 2 decimal places.

`TEXT( Number_1__c ) & ' to ' & TEXT( Number_2__c )`